# Saltstack load pillar in a for loop

Tags: templates, jinja2, salt-stack, jaml

I am developing a automatic proftd installation whit Salt, i wont to get the ftp users from a template but I cant get work the pillar, i initialized the pillar whit the users data and call it into a for loop, but you don't get the pillar user data in the loop.

When i make  salt-call pillar.get ftpusers in the minion, the response is:

local:

This is my pillar ftpusers.sls:

```
ftp-server.ftpusers:
  user:
    - user: user
    - passhash: j2k3hk134123l1234ljh!"·$ser
    - uuid: 1001
    - guid: 1001
    - home: /srv/ftp/user
    - shel: /bin/false
```

And this is the for loop:

```
{% for users in pillar.get('ftpusers', {}).items() %}

  /srv/herma-ftp/.ftpusers:
    file.managed:
      - user: root
      - group: root
      - mode: 444
      - contents:'{{ user }}:{{ args['passhash'] }}:{{args['uuid'] }}:{{ args['guid'] }}::{{ args['home'] }}:{{ args['shel'] }}'
      - require:
        - file: /srv/herma-ftp

  /srv/herma-ftp/{{user}}:
    file.directory:
      - user: nobody
      - group: nobody
      - dir_mode: 775
      - makedirs: True
      - require:
        - file: /srv/herma-ftp
      - watch:
        - file: /srv/herma-ftp
    module.run:
      - name: file.set_selinux_context
      - path: {{ args['home']}}
      - type: public_content_t
      - unless:
        - stat -c %C {{ args['home'] }} |grep -q public_content_t

{% endfor %}
```

When I make in the minion

```
salt-call -l debug state.sls herma-ftp-server saltenv=My-enviroment test=True
```

Don't expect this for because don't can get the pillar data.

Comment: It appears you are using a local masterless installation. Please share your minion configuration and your `top.sls` files (for pillar and states). Also, please include the error you get as it appears you have missed it in the question.

Comment: - contents:'{{ user }}:{{ args['passhash'] }}:{{args['uuid'] }}:{{ args['guid'] }}::{{ args['home'] }}:{{ args['shel'] }}' the fail is in this line, how I can skip the single colons?

Answer (score 4):

Your loop should also look like:

```
{% for user, args in pillar.get('ftpusers', {}).items() %}
```

Also, `contents` argument for a `file.managed` doesn't support templating. What you need to do is move `/srv/herma-ftp/.ftpusers` state outside of the loop, and make the loop inside the file template. The final layout of your state should look like:

```
/srv/herma-ftp/.ftpusers
  file.managed:
    source: salt://ftpserver/dot.ftpusers
    template: jinja
    ...
    ...

{% for user, args in pillar.get('ftpusers', {}).items() %}

/srv/herma-ftp/{{user}}:
  file.managed:
    ...

{% endfor %}
```

And your `ftpserver/dot.ftpusers` would look like:

```
{% for user, args in pillar.get('ftpusers', {}).items() %}
{{ user }}:{{ args['passhash'] }}:{{args['uuid'] }}:{{ args['guid'] }}::{{ args['home'] }}:{{ args['shel'] }}
{% endfor %}
```