# Apply user-name from roster as variable in a salt state

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a roster with some hosts/users:

```
myhos1:
  host: 192.168.1.1
  user: foouser

myhost2:
  host: 192.168.1.2
  user: bazuser
```

Now in the state file I would like to use the username from the roster to do things, e.g.

```
Install VNC script:
  file.managed:
    - name: /home/<user>/test.sh
    - source: salt://files/test.sh
    - user: <user>
    - group: <user>
```

How do I use the template language to replace `<user>` with the actual user-id of the host that I apply the state to?

Would be nice if I can somehow directly access the information from the roster, but I did not find anything that would work in the relevant docu-pages.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options that I can think of.

If you've not many users the easiest option would be to just loop over a list using jinja

```
{% for user in ['foouser', 'bazuser'] %}
/home/{{ user }}/test.sh:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://files/test.sh
    - user: {{ user }}
    - group: {{ user }}
{% endfor %}
```

or you should be able to do something like use `cmd.run` to get a list of users:

```
 {% for user in salt['cmd.run']('ls /home/').split('\n') %}
    ... snipped
 {% endfor %}
```

I have tested the above and it works for me.

[cmd.run in jinja - google salt-users forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/6r3gCPyzOyg)

[Useful reading if you're unsure about using Jinja with Salt](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/config/jinja.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Ideally I would like to get the one single user that is used to connect to the machine in the roster-file, but your second approach will likely be a useful workaround in the meantime.

Comment: @centic ah, sorry I should really put my glasses on. Have you tried using a pillar file and looping over the contents? See answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169509/saltstack-load-pillar-in-a-for-loop. I should probably edit my question to include this